# HotChocolate gives me "Cannot access a disposed context instance." for my DB Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql, hotchocolate

I use GraphQL library `HotChocolate`.

Program.cs:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services
        .AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddQueryType<ProductQuery>();


    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DpcDatabaseContext>();
 // ...

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapGraphQL();
    
    app.Run();
```

I got my context using constructor injection:

```
  public DpcProductDatabaseService(DpcDatabaseContext dpcDatabaseContext)
    {
        _dpcDatabaseContext = dpcDatabaseContext;
      
    }
```

And how I get products:

```
        var res = await _dpcDatabaseContext.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Id == 1, cancellationToken);
```

And what I get:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'DpcDatabaseContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DpcMicroService.Services.DpcProductDatabaseService.GetProductsByFilterFromDbInternalAsync(FilterInput filter, DpcDatabaseContextBase ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Beeline\DpcMicroService\DpcMicroService\DpcMicroService\Services\DpcProductDatabaseService.cs:line 86
```

Where Im I wrong? If I create my context manually using `new` it works. But this is not a way out for me. Please, helpme to figure out what is wrong.

I also tried to configure DI in this way:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DpcDatabaseContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

It did not have any effect.

Comment: Where do you register `DpcProductDatabaseService` and what's its scope? A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit of Work. DbContext is meant to be scoped, not transient and any dependencies should be scoped as well. The scope in a web application is the HTTP request which means that if you try to use a DbContext after a request ends, you'll get an ObjectDisposedException. I suspect `DpcProductDatabaseService` is a Singleton or BackgroundService (which is Singleton)

Comment: Did you check HotChocolate's [Entity Framework Core guide](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/integrations/entity-framework) ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  forgot to mention. It was ` builder.Services.AddScoped<DpcProductDatabaseService>();`
But! If we speak about lifetime, is it ok to try `builder.Services.AddSingleton<DpcProductDatabaseService>();  builder.Services.AddDbContext<DpcDatabaseContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);` what do you think? I it ok for Db Context to be a singletone?

Comment: Never. I repeat, a DbContext is a Unit of Work. It keeps track of all pending changes and saves *all* of them when SaveChanges is called. To discard the changes you dispose the DbContext or let DI do so when the scope ends. If you make it a Singleton, changes that were made by a completely different request or 2 requests in the past will still be active and get saved when you call `SaveChanges`

Comment: You should really, really check the EF Core guide instead of trying at random.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no idea how did I miss this page (documentation about EF integration). The page contained all I needed to resolve the problem. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core